# media message incoming Bubble type not proper in jsqMessageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

can anyone have idea about showing wrong bubble on incoming media. text messages bubbles are working fine  [image: this]

```
  JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory *bubbleFactory = [JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory new];

    self.outgoingBubbleImageData = [bubbleFactory outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor jsq_messageBubbleRedColor]];
    self.incomingBubbleImageData = [bubbleFactory incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor jsq_messageBubbleBlueColor]];
```

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: @Losiowaty i am using jsqmessageviewcontroller library for chatting https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

Comment: Ok, so you instantiate your bubbles correctly. Now show how/where you use them.

Comment: @VarinderSingh use this code self.outgoingBubbleImageData = [bubbleFactory outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor jsq_messageBubbleLightGrayColor]];
        self.incomingBubbleImageData = [bubbleFactory incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor jsq_messageBubbleGreenColor]];

Comment: @IOS_DEV i have tried..Not working brother

Comment: only media messages... like images, video and audio showing wrong bubble.... text messages Bubbles working fine

Comment: See this post on github: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/650

Comment: Solved..Thanks @RomanRoba

Answer (score 0):

```
- (id<JSQMessageData>)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView messageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
JSQMessage *message = [self.chatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
// Determine if the message has media content
if (message.isMediaMessage)
{
    // Incoming or outgoing message?
    if (![message.senderId isEqualToString:self.senderId]) {
        [((JSQMediaItem *)message.media) setAppliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing:NO]; // Override default setting to allow incoming media message
    }
}

return message;
```

}

Got answer from [Here](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/650)

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly i have to tell you that this library is deprecated now you should it wisely or use another library. source -  [officially deprecated](https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/officially-deprecating-jsqmessagesviewcontroller/)

You have to just remember when your `jsqmessagemedia` type is outgoing or incoming message object

if your `jsqmessage` type is `jsqphotomediaitem` you have to just configure as follows before appending it to your message array

```
    JSQPhotoMediaItem *mediaItem = [[JSQPhotoMediaItem alloc]initWithImage:yourImage];
       if(yourMessageObjectIsOutGoing == YES){
            mediaItem.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = YES;
       }else{
        mediaItem.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = NO;
       }
    arrMessages.append(mediaItem)
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
```

same goes for anyMedia Object like `JSQVideoMediaItem`